# Xcode - Umbrella framework - missing modules

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I built an umbrella framework using Xcode 10.1, it works fine as long as computer the framework is built and the project it goes in are the same computer. As soon as I hand the framework off to someone else, on a different computer, it errors saying that the main framework can’t find the sub-frameworks "Missing required modules:".

I’ve tried changing the import paths and framework search paths in the project, but nothing seems to work. Same error.

This is the tutorial I followed, https://medium.com/@bittudavis/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-swift-ca964d0a2345, and if you search for "Missing required" it seems someone is having the same issue on his example project.

Thanks for any input.